# Getting most popular tags

Tags: php, mysql, string, csv, count

Writing a query that returns like the table below. What I am trying to do is get the popularity of tags based on the results returned.

```
SELECT thing, tags from table WHERE field LIKE '%thing%';

+----+------------+------------------+
| id | thing      | tags             |
+----+------------+------------------+
| 1  | thing1     | tag1, tag2, tag3 |
| 2  | thing2     | tag1, tag4, tag5 |
| 3  | thatthing  | tag1, tag2, tag5 |
| 4  | thisthing  | tag3, tag4, tag5 |
+----+--------+----------------------+
```

Trying to write a query that will return tag popularity like this...

```
+---------------------+-------+
| tag                 | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| tag1                | 3     |
| tag5                | 3     |
| tag2                | 2     |
| tag3                | 2     |
| tag4                | 2     |
+---------------------+-------+
```

or even maybe just return from the initial query with just the tags and counts for each.

Comment: Normalize your table and it will be much easier. You should have a table like `thing_tags` where each row in the table has the `id` for the `thing`, and a single tag. This allows you to have multiple rows for the same `thing` to assign multiple tags (one to many relationship). This is the proper way to use a relational database like mysql. It's _almost_ never a good idea/plan to store a comma separates list of strings.

Comment: You have several tags in one column, and for mysql engine, this is just a string. Because you want to distinguish between tags for building this query, you will need tooling at mysql engine level for manipulating strings, splitting etc.. which is quite poor.  As already stated, best would be to normalize the table structure, i.e always to have a single tag per column. You just need a third table, a relational table as they call it, where you describe the many-to-many relations between things and tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first effort should go into fixing your data model. Do not store multiple values in a delimited list.

You should have a separate table to store the relations between things and tags, with eac tuple on a different row.

Table `things`:

```
id     thing
-------------
1      thing1
2      thing2
```

Table `tags`:

```
id      tag
------------
1       tag1
2       tag2
```

Table `things_tags`:

```
thing_id    tag_id
------------------
1           1
1           2
2           2
```

Then, couting the popularity of each tag is as simple as:

```
select t.tag, count(*) cnt
from tags t
inner join things_tags tt on tt.tag_id = t.id
group by t.id
order by cnt desc
```

On the other hand, a design such as yours makes it much more complicated to maintain data integrity and manipulate the values. What you ask for would typically require a recursive query to split the csv strings into elements.

Recommended reading: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/10676716).